# Date fields in MySQL table not getting updated

Tags: mysql, toad

I am using a table in MySQL (table name: th_group_rating) where I have a date field 'as_on_dt'. I want to update all the NULL fields (73 records in the table with null values) from this column and replace it with any date.

Properties of the column:
It can accept null values (Not Null is set as FALSE), 
Default value is set to '0000-00-00' and the Datatype is DATE

What I have tried so far:

**Attempt 1:** `update th_group_rating set as_on_dt = '0000-00-00' where as_on_dt is null;
commit;`

**Attempt 2:** `update th_group_rating set as_on_dt = '0000-00-00' where as_on_dt = ''; commit;`

**Result:** still shows NULL values

One strange thing that I have observed is,  When I fetch records using the following query, I get records where as_on_dt is null. 
Query: `select * from th_group_rating where as_on_dt = '0000-00-00'`

Result:
All 73 records where as_on_dt is NULL

**Attempt 3:** After seeing the above result, I tried updating the table using this query: `update th_group_rating set as_on_dt = '0000-00-00' where as_on_dt = '0000-00-00'; commit;`

**Result:** NULL values still present

Now I am stuck here since this is a task that I have to perform in order to move ahead. BTW, I am using Toad for MySQL (just for all of you to know)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

[Sample NULL records can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ltfg.png)

[Sample data from the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8R1Y.png)

Comment: MySQL doesn't support year zero in DATE. Why do you want to set it as such?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen this is not correct, mysql can be configured to allow zero dates using no_zero_date sql mode setting. And I think this setting has sg to do with this question.

Comment: Ohhh... I didn't know that MySQL doesn't support zero year date. It supports in SQL Server and I have worked majorly on SQL Server. I just don't want NULL values to be present. Thanks for the info. I'lll try to replace the NULL values with any other date.

Comment: @Shadow Interesting, documentation doesn't mention that immediately. Still, having an invalid date rather than NULL is a bit weird design.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen mysql manual on the date data types does say that you can use zero dates and references this sql mode setting.

Comment: @AkshayFadnavis do you get warnings after the conversion to zero date? Do you connect via mysql's odbc connector to the server?

Comment: Version 5.7 documentation doesn't, only says invalid dates will become zero. But in any case, NULL has a reason to be there. If you use some random date then the data is invalid since that date isn't the actual date it is supposed to be.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I suggest you re-read the documentation again in this case.

Comment: @Shadow Well, I don't think my browser's find function is this broken, but this isn't the place to talk about that. This page has no mention of the setting in any case. There may be other pages that do.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I do not doubt your browser's find functionality. The question is whether you search on the right page for the right expression. `MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode.` See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html